# SilverStripe - Get a page's form value with a function

Tags: php, mysql, silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1 I'm trying to get the value of my Hello Bar selector to be accessible by pages site wide.

I've created the dropdown field to select the contents on the `HomePage.php` so I'm having no problem referencing the fields value on the home page. The value of the dropdown will inform the if block to run and what to populate the hello bar with.

**Page.php**

```
..//

public function HelloBarSelector() {
    $Selector = HomePage::get()->HelloBarSelect;
    return $Selector;
}

public function ShowHelloBar($itemID = 1) {
    $HelloBars = HelloBar::get()->byID($itemID);
    $HelloBars = $HelloBars->HelloBarText;
    return $HelloBars;
}

..//
```

**Includes/HelloBar.ss**

```
<% if $HelloBarSelector %>
<section class="hello">
    <p class="hello__text">$ShowHelloBar($HelloBarSelector)</p>
</section>
<% end_if %>
```

**HomePage.php**

```
..//

public function getCMSFields(){
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.HelloBar', GridField::create(
        'HelloBars',
        'Hello Bar Text', 
        $this->HelloBars(),
        GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
    ));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.HelloBar', DropdownField::create(
            'HelloBarSelect',
            'Choose Your Hello Bar (this will be sitewide)',
            HelloBar::get()->map('ID', 'HelloBarText')
        )
        ->setEmptyString('(none)'));
    return $fields;
}

..//
```

I have no issues accessing the value with `$HelloBarSelect` on the home page and all works as expected. It seems the problem is accessing the `$HelloBarSelect` with my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HomePage::get()` will return a DataList of HomePage DataObjects so you cant access the HelloBarSelect.

`HomePage::get()->First()` and `HomePage::get_one()` (assuming that you have only one homepage there) would return one DataOject. So if the field is right you can use `HomePage::get()->First()->HelloBarText`

Tip:

Use `Debug::dump(HomePage::get())` to see what you are manipulating. Its always good do dump out data to see what you are working on.

Also read: http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/ or watch these videos http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed and will really help me moving forward :)

Answer (score 0):

What does the `ShowHelloBar()` function does?

Try just using `$HelloBarSelector` instead of `$ShowHelloBar($HelloBarSelector)`

EDIT:

I see. Template functions doesn't take arguments, so in this case, $itemID will always be null.

Where are you getting `$itemID`? If it's somewhere in the request/query then you have to get it from that.

e.g.

```
public function ShowHelloBar() {
    //If you use the standard $Action/$ID/$OtherID handler
    $itemID = $this->getRequest()->param('ID'); 

    //If it's somewhere in $_GET like ?ID=3
    $itemID = $this->getRequest()->getVar('ID'); 

    $HelloBars = HelloBar::get()->byID($itemID);
    $HelloBars = $HelloBars->HelloBarText;
    return $HelloBars;
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't solve my issue. Please look at my updated code and it may make more sense as to why I need to get the value of the dropdown.

Comment: The function accepts a value when `HelloBar.ss` is loaded into the `HomePage.ss` layout so no, it won't always be null. `$itemID` is a a variable that's local to that function to allow me to pass a value (in this case the value of the dropdown list `$HelloBarSelector`) into the function.